# Firestore pagination appends array in wrong order

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to paginate through my messages from newest to oldest(bottom to up). My query works but it appends array in wrong order after I query new messages. I did follow [this](https://medium.com/@650egor/firestore-reactive-pagination-db3afb0bf42e) article. This is my logic:

```
//Global variables
let start = null
let end = null

collectionRef
      .orderBy('createTimestamp', 'desc')
      .limit(10)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        start = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]
        if (start) {
          const listener = collectionRef
            .orderBy('createTimestamp')
            .startAt(start)
            .onSnapshot(messages => {
              messages.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                const message = this.convertObjectTimestampPropertiesToDate({
                  id: change.doc.id,
                  ...change.doc.data()
                })
                if (change.type === 'added') {
                  store.commit('chats/addMessage', message)
                }
              })
            })
          store.commit('chats/setObserver', listener)
        }
      })
```

If I am on top of messages list then I start this function(And this is the part where the order of my messages goes wrong. It moves biggest timestamp items to up and small timestamp items to bottom, which is wrong.):

```
async getMoreMessages() {
    collectionRef
          .orderBy('createTimestamp', 'desc')
          .startAt(start)
          .limit(10)
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            end = start
            start = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]
            const listener = collectionRef
              .orderBy('createTimestamp')
              .startAt(start)
              .endBefore(end)
              .onSnapshot(messages => {
                messages.forEach(message => {
                  const mappedMessage = this.convertObjectTimestampPropertiesToDate(
                    {
                      id: message.id,
                      ...message.data()
                    }
                  )
                  store.commit('chats/addMessage', mappedMessage)
                })
              })
            store.commit('chats/setObserver', listener)
          })
       }
```

My Vuex mutation that adds message to the array:

```
addMessage: (state, message) => {
    const exists = state.messages.find(m => {
      return m.id === message.id
    })
    if (!exists) {
      state.messages.push(message)
    }
},
```

Here is visualisation what is going on:

[image]

And this is the console log of timestamps after I run `getMoreMessages()`:

```
    TEXT 9 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:09 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 10 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:10 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 11 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:11 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 12 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:12 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 13 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:13 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 14 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:14 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 15 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:15 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 16 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:16 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 17 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:18 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 18 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:19 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 1 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:13:24 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 2 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:13:43 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 3 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:13:50 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 4 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:05 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 5 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:06 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 6 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:07 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 7 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:08 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
chats.mutations.js?7021:29 TEXT 8 TIMESTAMP Wed Sep 25 2019 16:14:08 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
```

I can not understand what I am doing wrong. It seems that the query works fine but the append logic is failing. I tried to do `unshift()` instead of `.push()` and order by timestamp on frontend but it has wrong order also. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing `'desc'` in the orderBy? By default Firestore will use `asc` but I see in your first call you're specifying `desc`.

Comment: I do not use 'desc' where I neeed 'asc' and it is what it is supposed to be since I do query vice-versa in that point.

Comment: Can you please update with a better description of what you're getting and why it's wrong? Your visual is blurry and fast moving.

Comment: Also if you can include an idea of what the data looks like int he docs and the order of the data afterwards. I can't imagine that using descending to get an offset and then using the offset with ascending will actually work, but will accept that you say it's what you want.

Comment: It puts last items to first after I get new page. I edited question with ingo, where I did get the source idea.

Comment: Can you please update with a better description of what you're getting and why it's wrong?

Comment: I did update my question a little and this is full reso gif [here](https://imgur.com/a/BZWmKVt)

Comment: We don’t know what the numbers 1..18 mean. Can you print the timestamps? Is 1 the earliest or most recent?

Comment: 18 is most recent and 1 is oldest

Comment: I also added console log of timestamps and messages.